# Mediawiki API: Why does this query return an array rather than a map of pages?

Tags: json, http, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm making requests to a [wiki](https://japari-library.com) powered my the MediaWiki API. I'm using this query string for a GET:

```
action=query&format=json&prop=images|info&inprop=url&titles=<titles>
```

When I use a normal page, like ["Serval"](https://japari-library.com/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=images%7Cinfo&inprop=url&titles=Serval), the response looks something like this:

```
{
   "batchcomplete":"",
   "query":{
      "pages":{
         "34":{
             // page info
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is what my program expects, and as far as I can tell it's what the API promises.

But when I use a kind of weird page for the title, like ["|Main Page"](https://japari-library.com/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=images%7Cinfo&inprop=url&titles=%7CMain%20Page), I get a response that looks like this:

```
{
   "batchcomplete":"",
   "query":{
      "pages":[
         {
            "title":"",
            "invalidreason":"The requested page title is empty or contains only the name of a namespace.",
            "invalid":""
         },
         {
            "pageid":1,
            // info
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The `invalid` page I expect, but what I don't expect is that the `pages` element is an array rather than a map, and that the page has a new `pageid` element. I don't have an exhaustive list of pages that trigger this switch, but I can say that appending (or prepending) a regular page to the `titles` element in the query causes it to switch back to a map, like I expect.

What causes this? Is my workaround (prepending a known good page) the only way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `formatversion=2` to alway get a structure like that (changes some other things as well); it's a good practice anyway.

Comment: by "a structure like that" do you mean the map or the array?

Comment: `formatversion=2` will return pages in an array (and also uses `true` instead of `""` and might possibly include other small changes which make the result more JSON-ish).